# Get Sum for the column based on a condition

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, sum, window-functions

I am working on a SQL Query. Query is something like below:

```
Select 
    a.field1,
    b.field2,
    c.field3,
    c.field4,
    b.filed5,
    a.field6,
    d.field7 
from 
    a 
    Inner join b on a.field1 = b.field1 
    right join c on b.field2 = c.field3 
    left  join d on d.filed3 = a.field1 
where some conditions;
```

The output of the above would be something like this:

```
field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 | field6 | field7
--------------------------------------------------------------
name   | value1 | other1 | 1      | diff   |   new  | 100
name1  | value2 | other2 | 1      | diff1  |   new1 | 100
name2  | value3 | other3 | 2      | diff2  |   new2 | 100
```

So i need a new column in the result which sums the `field7` based on `field4` value(if they are same).

Is it in possible in SQL? I tried to use `Group by field 4` here but I am getting an error that `field1` should be used in group by. So i am not able get the result as expected.

Expected Result:

```
field1 | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5 | field6 | field7
--------------------------------------------------------------
name   | value1 | other1 | 1      | diff   |   new  | 200
some   | value3 | other3 | 2      | diff2  |   new2 | 100
```

Basically i want to remove one column based on a condition and sum the last field.

Any suggestions are helpful.

Comment: Would you please show us the results that should correspond to your sample data?

Comment: @GMB Done. So basically i want to remove the column based on field 1 after summing up the last field as mentioned above

Comment: Thanks! Another question: do `field1`...`field6` all have equal values in the resultset? If not, which record would you want to keep in the group?

Comment: You probably want to replace `'some'` in your sample data with some more meaningful data.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. In my opinion, your question looks good now!

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please always google your error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names, & read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. [ask] PS Your descriptions of what you want are unclear. Eg You don't explain "based on". Eg A "basically" or "essentially" or "in other words" that doesn't introduce or summarize a clear, precise & full description that you also give just means "unclearly".

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code plus desired output plus clear specification & explanation. Minimal means adding minimal problem code to minimal working code. So give minimal code that you show does what you expect & minimal code with the first place you go wrong. (Debugging fundamental.) But in this post: It is not necessary to involve any joins of multiple tables to ask this question. We can't cut & paste. You don't give the error messsage. And that should be a *first* question before this one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To compute the sum of `field7` in groups of records having the same `field4`, you can use window function `SUM(...) OVER(...)`.

To just keep one record per group of records having the same `field4`, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` in an inner query and filter out unwanted records in the outer query. Please note that you need a *sort criteria* to reliably choose which record should be kept in each group. I chose to use `field1` (change it as you need):

Your (pseudo-)query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        a.field1,
        b.field2,
        c.field3,
        c.field4,
        b.filed5,
        a.field6,
        SUM(d.field7) OVER(PARTITION BY c.field4) sm,
        ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY c.field4 ORDER BY a.field1) rn,
    FROM
        a 
        INNER JOIN b on a.field1 = b.field1 
        RIGHT JOIN c on b.field2 = c.field3 
        LEFT  JOIN d on d.field3 = a.field1 
    WHERE some conditions
) x
WHERE rn = 1
```

Hint: you can run the inner query independently to see what it returns (this helps understanding the logic).

Comment: looks like the Over Partition is giving me the wrong sum. Instead of 200, 100 i am getting 300,200 for the field7.

Comment: row number() didnt worked but Over Partition worked. Thanks . I have started a different thread to have more understanding on the other point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use partition by the query to create a separate partition according to field4 and then take the sum

```
SELECT
z.* FROM (SELECT
a.field1,
b.field2,
c.field3,
b.filed5,
a.field6,
SUM(d.field4) OVER (PARTITION BY a.field1, b.field2, c.field3, b.filed5, a.field6) AS field7,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY c.field4 ORDER BY c.field4) AS rank FROM a INNER JOIN b
ON a.field1 = b.field1 RIGHT JOIN c
ON b.field2 = c.field3 LEFT JOIN d
ON d.filed3 = a.field1 where some conditions; ) z WHERE z.rank = 1
```

Comment: Okay basically the same answer rename the sum column alias as field7 I have updated the answer

Comment: will this also delete the second unwanted column?

Comment: Looks like your query is adding up all the values on field7 even if the field4 is different

Comment: Hi @Amila your first answer kind of worked. I am sorry but i didnt really understood your latest update :( any explanation will be helpful Thanks :)

Comment: Postgreql database

Comment: Please read the edit help re code block format. (Indent 4 spaces.)

Comment: @ging Code is changed according to the requirement.